# QWT installation file missing on ubuntu

Tags: c++, plot, qt-creator, qwt

I'm trying to install `QWT` library on my ubuntu machine to use it with `QT` and `cmake`. I used the synaptic package manager to download and install the version `6.0.0` but the problem is when I include `qwt/qwt.h` in my code I get the following the compilation error:

```
/usr/include/qwt/qwt_global.h:13:21: fatal error: qglobal.h: No such file or directory
 #include <qglobal.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

I could not find anything that fixes it. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://packages.ubuntu.com allows searching for filenames.

Searching for qglobal.h:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=qglobal.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any

So you need to install the qt development package either for qt4 or qt5